# Concurrency ExecutorService Counter from 1 to N

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Sup!

I am practicing & trying to cope with concurrency
Now, I am attempting to count numbers from 1 to N (1000 in my example) using ExecutorService, but unluckily I am not able to receive the expectative result. Here I go:

```
class Exec {
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        Exec exec = new Exec();
        exec.run(exec);
    }
}

public void run(Exec exec) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    IntStream.range(0, 1000).parallel().forEach(x -> executorService.submit(exec::synchCalc));

    executorService.shutdown();
    System.out.println(sum.get());
}
public synchronized void synchCalc() {
    sum.incrementAndGet();
} 
}
```

The output is:

```
940
980
976
973
1000
1000
960
968
969
996
969
969
1000
938
997
0
1000
999
1000
734
999
969
1000
238
969
999
969
971
465
999
```

I've tried several ways of solving my problem: **volatile** instead of **AtomicInteger**, **synchronizing** almost **every** method, but it doesn't make sense as well. The result is just the same - I never get all 1000 and I don't really realise why so.

I would appreciate any answer in due trouble.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi, have a look at the duplicates for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830328/1366871 explains what is wrong with your code

Comment: You don't need the synchronized, you just need to wait before calling sum.get()

Comment: @dreamcrash thank u so much! It works! Cheers =)

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :)